# Is there a way to access Google News stories from a particular date?

Tags: google-search, google-news

I want to read news stories that were published on a particular date like say 15th October, 2022.

Google News provides an easy way for us to see all the news articles at a single place.However, I am unable to figure out how to see news articles from a particular date. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### News by Date Range

To search for articles dated "15th October, 2022":

1. Navigate to [news.google.com](https://news.google.com/) **<sup>1</sup>**
2. use the search term "after:2022-10-15 before:2022-10-16"

<sub>**<sup>1</sup>**  *You can use the same search modifier in regular Google searches at google.com with or without category filters such as* `Books`, `Images`, `Shopping`, *and of course* `News`</sub>

---

screenshot: **news.google.com**

[image: Google News]

---

screenshot: **google.com `News`**

[image: google.com]

---